# package ‘RTN’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1)

Tags: r, package, rstudio, bioconductor

I got this when I am trying to install package from bioconductor, but it seems it does not work properly. The manual of this package is here:

http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/manuals/RTN/man/RTN.pdf

The package name is RTN.

```
    biocLite("RTN")
    BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org Using Bioconductor version 2.12 (BiocInstaller
    1.10.4), R version 3.0.1.
    Installing package(s) 'RTN'
    Warning messages:
    1: package ‘RTN’ is not available (for R version 3.0.1) 
    2: installed directory not writable, cannot update
       packages 'class', 'foreign', 'lattice', 'MASS',
       'Matrix', 'mgcv', 'nlme', 'nnet', 'rpart',
       'spatial', 'survival' 
    > library(RTN)
    Error in library(RTN) : there is no package called ‘RTN’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of Bioconductor (2.12) is too old for RTN, which was introduced (see the [RTN landing page](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/RTN.html)) in Bioconductor 2.13. I think you can say

```
 source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
 biocLite("BiocUpgrade")
```

but (a) this might require that your R be updated and (b) it will likely update (re-install) any existing Bioconductor and perhaps some CRAN packages, so you should be prepared for a few bumps in the road.